# Packaging a single python file along with an "extras" package

Tags: python, namespaces, packaging

I currently have a project called "peewee" which consists of a single python file, peewee.py.  There is also a module "tests.py" containing unit tests.  This has been great, people that want to use the library can just grab a single file and run with it.

I've lately wanted to add some extras, but am not sure how to do this to make the namespacing right.  If you look in the root of my project, it is something like:

```
peewee.py
tests.py
```

I want to add the following:

```
extras/__init__.py
extras/foo.py
extras/bar.py
```

And this is the tricky part.  I want to have it such that folks using the single file can still do this, but if you want the extras you can have them, too.  I want the extras to be namespaced such that:

```
from peewee.extras import foo
from peewee.extras.bar import Baz
```

My setup.py looks a bit like this:

```
setup(
    name='peewee',
    packages=['extras'],
    py_modules=['peewee'],
    # ... etc ...
)
```

But this doesn't quite work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no good way to do that - to have a namespace like that, you need to make `peewee` into a package (a folder with an `__init__.py` file). There might be ways round it, but clever tricks with namespaces aren't going to be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

### Setting Up a Package

As @ThomasK said, the easiest way to do this would be with a package.  If you name your package `peewee`, then you can edit the top-level `__init__.py` file to allow users to continue to use your package in the same way they have previously.

First, directory structure for your package and subfolders:

```
peewee/
    __init__.py
    peewee.py
    extras/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
```

#### The `__init__.py` file

Next, you need to add a few lines to the top-level `__init__.py`.

You could go for a quick-and-dirty method and just include:

```
from peewee.peewee import *
```

which would put everything in `peewee.py` in the top-level namespace of your package.  Or, you could take the more traditional alternative and explicitly import only those methods that should be at the top level.

```
from peewee.peewee import funtion1, class1,...
```

and, for backwards compatibility, you could explicitly set the `__all__` attribute of your module to include only peewee

```
__all__ = ['peewee']
```

which will let people continue to use `from peewee import *` if they really need to.

#### Writing a `setup.py` file

Finally, you'll have to set up some install scripts and such too.  Zed Shaw's [Learn Python The Hard Way exercise 46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) has a simple and clear project skeleton that you should use.

The most important part is the `setup.py` file. The example page isn't too long and Zed's put a lot of work into making a really great book, so I'm not going to repost it here (though the entire book is available for *free*). You can also read the longer instructions/documentation for [writing a setup.py file for distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html), however LPTHW will give you something that will do everything you want quickly and easily.

#### Total package directory structure

Note that your final directory structure will actually be a bit bigger (the name of `peewee-pkg` doesn't matter, `bin` is optional--the names of the subfolders matter)

```
peewee-pkg/
    setup.py
    bin
    peewee/
        __init__.py
        peewee.py
        extras/
            __init__.py
            foo.py
            bar.py
```

### Installing and using

After that, you could actually post your package to PyPi if you like, or you can distribute it to users directly.  All they would need to do is run:

```
 python setup.py install
```

and everything will be available to them.

#### Importing post-install

Finally, if you do specific imports in the `peewee/__init__.py` file as described earlier, your users will still be able to do:

```
from peewee import function1, class1, ...
```

But now they can also use `import peewee.extras` to get to the extras functions (or `import peewee.extras.foo as foo` or `from pewee.extras.foo import extra_awesome`), etc. And, as you asked in your question, they will also be able to do:

```
from pewee.extras import foo
```

And then access `foo`'s functions as if the file were in the current directory.

### Useful note for developing a package

On your computer, you should run:

```
python setup.py develop
```

which will install the package to your path just like using `python setup.py install`; however, `develop` tells python to recheck the file every time it uses the module, so that every time you make changes, they will be immediately available to the system for testing.